# mysql триггер сравнивающий поля в разных табилцах

Tags: mysql, триггер

[image: Вот моя модель]

В общем вопрос такой, хочу написать триггер на то чтобы в таблице журнал учета больничных листов в поле дата закрытия не заходили данные, если дата закрытия меньше чем дата приема в таблице прием у врача. Спасибо!`

```
create table sick_list(
id_list int zerofill not null auto_increment,
id_visitdate int unsigned not null ,
from_date date not null ,
to_date date ,
note varchar (255),
foreign key(id_visitdate) references conclusion (id_visitdate),
primary key (id_list) );`

    create table doctors_visit(
id_doctor int unsigned not null,
id_visitdate int unsigned not null auto_increment,
id_timesheet int unsigned not null,
visit_date date not null,
primary key (id_visitdate),
foreign key (id_doctor) references doctors (id_doctor),
foreign key (id_timesheet) references work_absense (id_timesheet) );`

`create table conclusion(
id_visitdate int unsigned not null,
unwork_reason varchar (10) not null,
foreign key (id_visitdate) references doctors_visit (id_visitdate),
primary key (id_visitdate) );

create table sicklist_stat(
id_list int (10) unsigned zerofill not null auto_increment,
closing_date date not null,
foreign key (id_list) references sick_list (id_list),
primary key (id_list) );
```

Comment: Хотите написать, напишите. А вопрос то в чем ? Если хотите что бы это сделали за вас, вы ошиблись сайтом, вам на биржу фриланса

Comment: Просто не знал как это сделать, думал подскажут как. Энивэй уже сделано)